# How to not return result if one value is null?

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a top level weight for a shipment but within that there is several weights for  handling units. If one of these handling units has no value then I want the shipment to not show up in my query.

Here is my query -

```
`SELECT DISTINCT S.SHIPMENT_ID,
                            S.STATE,
                            S.CONTRACT,
                            CASE
                                WHEN H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT <> '0' THEN
                                 SUM(H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT)
                                ELSE
                                 NULL
                            END MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT
FROM   SHIPMENT S
JOIN   HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT H
ON     H.SHIPMENT_ID = S.SHIPMENT_ID
WHERE  S.STATE = 'Preliminary'
         AND S.CONTRACT = 'BVL10'
         AND H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT <> '0'
GROUP  BY S.SHIPMENT_ID,
                S.STATE,
                S.CONTRACT,
                H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT`
```

This returns 123 as there is currently two boxs, one with a manual weight of 123 and one with 0.

It should not return this shipment at all as one of the manual weights is 0.

Comment: provider sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Use HAVING clause!

Comment: @jarlh Can you show me please

Comment: Which flavour of SQL is this?

Comment: @Nick It is oracle

Comment: I'm surprised it's not complaining about using `NULL` in the `MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT` expression since that doesn't involve an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use `LEFT JOIN` for this.  I would simply use a `HAVING` clause.  Assuming the weights are never negative:

```
SELECT S.SHIPMENT_ID, S.STATE, S.CONTRACT,
       SUM(H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT) as MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT
FROM SHIPMENT S JOIN
     HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT H
     ON H.SHIPMENT_ID = S.SHIPMENT_ID 
WHERE S.STATE = 'Preliminary' AND S.CONTRACT = 'BVL10'       
GROUP BY S.SHIPMENT_ID, S.STATE, S.CONTRACT
HAVING MIN(H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT) > 0;
```

If the weight could be `0` and you have negative values, then:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never used with `GROUP BY`.  In this query, it is not needed.

EDIT:

If you want to filter out any shipment that has a `NULL` weight:

```
HAVING COUNT(H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT) = COUNT(*)
```

This requires that all be non-`NULL`.

Comment: What if the value is quite often Null? In which case if one weight is null I don't want the shipment to show at all. It's never zero, its either null or has a value against each row and if one row is null then i want it to not show that shipment as essentially the data isnt complete

Comment: You can add `AND H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT IS NOT NULL` to the `WHERE` clause.  That will filter out shipments where all the values are `NULL`.

Comment: It doesn't, so if there is two weights under the shipment. One is null and one has a value then I don't want that shipment to be returned, with the where you mentioned the shipment will still be returned with just the weight that exists, ignoring the fact theres a NULL weight..

Comment: @mfgn . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` and include `H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT <> '0'` in the `JOIN` condition, then by comparing the count of rows from `SHIPMENT` with those from `HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT` you can see which shipments had no zero weights (as the counts will be the same):

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.SHIPMENT_ID,
                            S.STATE,
                            S.CONTRACT,
                            SUM(H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT) MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT
FROM   SHIPMENT S
JOIN   HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT H
ON     H.SHIPMENT_ID = S.SHIPMENT_ID AND H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT <> '0'
WHERE  S.STATE = 'Preliminary'
         AND S.CONTRACT = 'BVL10'       
GROUP  BY S.SHIPMENT_ID,
          S.STATE,
          S.CONTRACT
HAVING COUNT(S.SHIPMENT_ID) = COUNT(H.SHIPMENT_ID)
```

Note this allows you to remove the `CASE` expression as it will only return shipments for which all `MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT` values are non-zero.

Comment: What I mean is if any of the manual gross weights are null, so in this case one of them is then no row should be returned as this shipment isn't completed essentially cause some rows dont have the weights filled in. Do you get me?

Comment: @mfgn this query will do that. If a shipment has any 0 or NULL values in `HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT`, the `LEFT JOIN` will return all `NULL` values for that row. Then when we do the `COUNT`, the count of `S.SHIPMENT_ID` will be higher than that of `H.SHIPMENT_ID` (because that had a `NULL` value) and so that shipment will not be displayed.

Comment: @mfgn I don't think your edit is correct. No values will pass a `<> NULL` test. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a6b876c215fc9d12b1aaf53612f2be5

Comment: @mfgn but if the value is `NULL`, it will fail the `<> 0` test, just as a `0` value will.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.SHIPMENT_ID,
                            S.STATE,
                            S.CONTRACT,
                            SUM(H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT) MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT
FROM   SHIPMENT S
JOIN   HANDLING_UNIT_SHIPMENT H
ON     H.SHIPMENT_ID = S.SHIPMENT_ID
         AND H.MANUAL_GROSS_WEIGHT <> NULL
WHERE  S.STATE = 'Preliminary'
         AND S.CONTRACT = 'BVL10'
 GROUP  BY S.SHIPMENT_ID,
                S.STATE,
                S.CONTRACT
HAVING COUNT(S.SHIPMENT_ID) = COUNT(H.SHIPMENT_ID)
```